# Nginx blocks grafana Iframe

Tags: nginx, iframe, grafana

I'm trying to embed a Grafana graphic in an iframe in my reverse proxy Nginx, but Firefox keeps blocking the iframe despite explicitly declaring on `nginx.conf` to accept to load iframes from the Grafana URI:

**Blocked IFrame**

[image: IFrame]

**Nginx allow XFrame line on server block**

```
add_header X-Frame-Options http://localhost:3000;
```

By watching the response header to GET index.html request, It seems that Nginx is accepting that configuration:

[image: get]

But when HTTP GET request is performed to obtain the Grafana chart, then in the response's header, X-Frame  param has changed to `DENY`:

[image]

Clearly I'm missing something.Maybe I should make the same change on Grafana server configuration file? Anyone can help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Grafana config needs `allow_embedding=true`.

Comment: Yeah, that’s was the thing! Thanks